How to average only the values of unique rows in a Pivot Table/Power Pivot
I have a data set that has three columns - a serial number, a category, and a price. Certain serial numbers are listed multiple times in the data set with different categories, but each one always has the same price. (Sample below)
Serial Num Category Price
12345         1      100
12345         2      100
45678         1       50
23456         2       75
98765         1       80
98765         2       80 

I would like to be able to create a pivot table with a filter on category that is calculating the average price, but that only counts the price of each serial number once when calculating that average. In the example in the picture, I want it to use 12345's price only once even though it is listed twice, but if I filter on either Category 1 or Category 2 I want 12345's price to factor into the average calculation.
Does anyone know if this is possible? Or if there is another way to do this other than just a regular pivot table or Power Pivot?

you say each serial number has the same price regardless of category. That means calculating their average will also return you the exact same values. Honestly I can't see where the problem is. Could you please post some screenshots with the issue?

It sounds like you want to calculate a "weighted" (vs "arithmetic") average. A search for "excel pivot table weighted average" should answer your question. I do agree with @MátéJuhász, if your price doesn't change then weighted average = arithmetic average.

@Maria ,, since price are similar then in this case the Pivot table can't put any noticeable difference,,, but if U add more data with different price in different category the U will get expected results ,,,, let me remind PT automatically creates Unique list !

Change the PivotTable Value Sum field to Average field.
